# Regex for css data attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, css, regex, uncss

Trying to post-process some CSS here and need a regex to select data-attribute selectors in CSS.

It will need to select the following selectors (just the selector but in it's entirety):

```
[data-attr] {
 // some css
}

.cool-class[data-another-attr] {
 // some css
}

#id[data-one-more-attr] {
 //  some css
}
```

So that would select `[data-attr]`, `.cool-class[data-another-attr]` and `#id[data-one-more-attr]`.

[What I have so far](http://regexr.com/3be7j) (not even close):

`/(\[data-*)\w/g`

Thanks in advance for your help, RegEx always stumps me.

Comment: Do you need only the name of `data` attribute or all the style properties in it

Comment: Might be a bit too loose, but this will get you started I guess: `/([.+]?\[data\-(.+)\])/g`: http://regexr.com/3be7m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following `regex`

```
((#|\.)?[\w-]+)?(\[data(-\w+)+\])/g
```

**Explanation:**

1. `(#|\.)?`: Matches `#` or `.` literal optionally
2. `[\w-]+`: Matches any alphanumeric character with `-` any number of times
3. `((#|\.)?[\w-]+)?`: Matches CSS `id` or `class` selector optionally(`?`)
4. `(\[data(-\w+)+\])`: Matches `data` attribute

[**Demo**](http://regexr.com/3be7p)

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uG1gT6/1)